# Export particle system to meshes (stl/obj whatever) without converting

Tags: scripting, particles, export, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create rubble-pile objects for a simulation. My simulation code can import STLs or OBJ files. These rubble-piles need to be made of many smaller constituent meshes that follow a certain size distribution. See my image where the number of smaller objects is much greater than that of the large objects.

[image]

I have a particle system that uses an object collection to fill a volume (in this case, the Itokawa surface mesh), and I may at times need 50,000+ particles/objects. Blender has no problem generating this distribution, and does so basically instantly. But if I want to export it, I have to convert all 50,000+ particles to instanced meshes first, and this either A) takes forever, or B) crashes Blender. It also makes exporting 50,000 objects to a single file a major chore. Is there some way, possibly with scripting, to just stream the particle system straight to an exported mesh file without having to create instanced objects in the object tree (or without having to create every instanced object all at once)? Or does anyone know when something like this can be done with Geometry Nodes that acts like a modifier (since the export applies modifiers upon export)?

I have found that if I create a second object and give it the modifier of "Particle Instance" and point it to the main object that has the particle emitter, I get half of what I want, in the sense that it is an exportable collection of instanced objects, but the instanced objects are all just clones of the object with the modifier and doesn't respect the size distribution.

Comment: BTW if you want to let us inspect your file share it via https://blend-exchange.com with only objects needed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: OK ... Have you tried Alembic export ... or decimate rubble-pile instances low-res before export... Or to use geo nodes instead?  I'm not sure we can help... We don't know how dense elements are ... Even you will share your file we use different hardware processing power so it wouldn't be easy say what could work for you.